# Merge cell in word using openxml

Tags: vb.net, openxml-sdk

I tried to do merge the table cell in word using openxml.Below are my code,but it does not perform the outcome that i want(merge table cell).
Can anyone help, Thanks in advance.

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit On
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing

Public Class Form1
Const fileName As String = "C:\Users\ericc\Desktop\test for new task\123.docx"
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, True)
        Dim doc = document.MainDocumentPart.Document
        ' Create an empty table.
        Dim table As New Table()

        ' Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
        Dim tblProp As New TableProperties(New TableBorders(
    New TopBorder() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of BorderValues)(BorderValues.Single), .Size = 1},
    New BottomBorder() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of BorderValues)(BorderValues.Single), .Size = 1},
    New LeftBorder() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of BorderValues)(BorderValues.Single), .Size = 1},
    New RightBorder() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of BorderValues)(BorderValues.Single), .Size = 1},
    New InsideHorizontalBorder() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of BorderValues)(BorderValues.Single), .Size = 1},
    New InsideVerticalBorder() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of BorderValues)(BorderValues.Single), .Size = 1}))
        ' Append the TableProperties object to the empty table.
        table.AppendChild(Of TableProperties)(tblProp)

        ' Create a row.
        Dim tr As New TableRow()

        ' Create a cell.
        Dim tc1 As New TableCell()
        Dim TableCellproperties As TableCellProperties = New TableCellProperties

        ' Specify the width property of the table cell.
        tc1.Append(New TableCellProperties(New TableCellWidth()))
        tc1.Append(New TableCellProperties(New HorizontalMerge() With {.Val = MergedCellValues.Restart}))

        ' Specify the table cell content.
        tc1.Append(New Paragraph(New Run(New Text("some text"))))
        ' Append the table cell to the table row.
        tr.Append(tc1)

        ' Create a second table cell by copying the OuterXml value of the first table cell.
        Dim tc2 As New TableCell(tc1.OuterXml)

        ' Append the table cell to the table row.
        tr.Append(tc2)

        ' Append the table row to the table.
        table.Append(tr)

        ' Append the table to the document.
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table)
    End Using
    Process.Start(fileName)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Create a simple Word document with a small table, no merged cells - save it. Merge a cell, then save this under a different name. Open the first in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and use the Tool to *compare* it with the second document. The tool should show you the code you need to generate the second document from the first - how to merge a table cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HorizontalMerge has to be set for each cell in the table.

For example to create a single row table with the first cell being a regular one and the second one being merged from 2 cells, set the HorizontalMerge of cell1 to Restart, cell2 to Restart and cell3 to Continue.

In C# that looks like

```
Table table = New Table();
TableRow row = new TableRow();

TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
cell1.TableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties();
cell1.TableCellProperties.HorizontalMerge = new HorizontalMerge { Val =  MergedCellValues.Restart };
// Add a content paragraph.
row.Append(cell1);

TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
cell2.TableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties();
cell2.TableCellProperties.HorizontalMerge = new HorizontalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Restart };
// Add a content paragraph.
row.Append(cell2);

TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
cell3.TableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties();
cell3.TableCellProperties.HorizontalMerge = new HorizontalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Continue };
// Add a content paragraph.
row.Append(cell3);

table.Add(row);
```